# Окно обратной связи, как позиционировать блоки ввода

Tags: html, css

Не передвигаются белые окна ввода. Как это сделать? Буду очень благодарна за совет или помощь. Спасибо!

```css
.call{
 position:relative;
 top: 173px;
 left: 450px; 
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: 'Arial Regular', sans-serif;
 z-index: 30px;
 height: 50px;
 
 
}
.call a{
  border: 1px solid #fecd39;
  padding: 15px 21px;
  background-color: #fecd39;
  color: #000;
}
.call a:hover {
 background-color: #e2aa00; 
 border-color: #e2aa00;
}
.call a:active {
 background-color: #e2aa00; 
 border-color: #785a00;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 2px rgba(120, 90, 0, 0.5) ;

}
.modal {
    position: fixed; /* фиксированное положение */
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(23,25,27,0.5); /* цвет фона */
    z-index: 1050;
    opacity: 0; /* по умолчанию модальное окно прозрачно */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in; 
    -moz-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 200ms ease-in; /* анимация перехода */
    pointer-events: none; /* элемент невидим для событий мыши */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* при отображении модального окно */
.modal:target {
    opacity: 1; /* делаем окно видимым */
   pointer-events: auto; /* элемент видим для событий мыши */
    overflow-y: auto; /* добавляем прокрутку по y, когда элемент не помещается на страницу */
}
/* ширина модального окна и его отступы от экрана */
.modal-dialog {
    position: relative;
    width: 39%;
    height: 244px;
    margin: 10px;

}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .modal-dialog {
      max-width: 500px;
      margin: 30px auto; /* для отображения модального окна по центру */
  }
}
/* свойства для блока, содержащего контент модального окна */ 
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #17191b;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px  rgba(255,255,255,.2);
    border-radius: .3rem;
    outline: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .modal-content {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
      /*box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);*/
  }
}
/* свойства для заголовка модального окна */
.modal-header {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 15px;
    }
.modal-title {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: "Roboto Regular" sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
/* свойства для кнопки "Закрыть" */
.close {
    float: right;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: none;
    
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* свойства для кнопки "Закрыть" при нахождении её в фокусе или наведении 
.close:focus, .close:hover {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .75;
}*/
/* свойства для блока, содержащего основное содержимое окна */
.modal-body {
  position: relative;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Roboto Regular" sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
.name {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
     <div class="call"><a href="#window" >ЗАКАЗАТЬ ЗВОНОК</a></div>
     <div id="window" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Введите контакты для связи</h3>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">×</a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">    
        <p>Ваше имя<br>
         Телефон<br>Электронная почта<br>Комментарий</p>
         <form id="contact-1" action="#" method="post" name="contact">
<input id="name" class="txt" name="name" type="name" placeholder="">
<input id="phone" class="txt" name="phone" type="phone" placeholder=""> 
<input id="email" class="txt" name="email" type="email" placeholder=""> 
<textarea id="msg" class="txtarea" name="msg" placeholder=""></textarea>
<button id="send">Заказать звонок</button>
</form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И как сделать такой градиент? просто градиент получился, при уменьшении значения opacity ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 0):

Советую изучить Bootstrap:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

https://jsfiddle.net/gvkm81uo/

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
<div class="modal-body">    
       <form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" value="email@example.com">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: по поводу гардиента задавайте цвета в формате rgba примеру rgba(0,0,0 .3).. .3 это opacity